# Check if my laptop has built-in microphone

Tags: hardware, microphone, lspci

How can I check if my laptop has built-in microphone ?
I have ubuntu 12.04 installed

Answer (score 4):

Select **System Settings**

Click on **Sound**

Click the **Input** tab and you should see **Internal Microphone**